# Opencv row assignmement different values

Tags: c++, opencv, matrix

I have this code in OpenCV:

```
cv::Mat1f codes(x,y);
...
for(int i=0; i<codes.rows ; i++){ //you don't care about n
  cv::Mat code(1,codes.cols, codes.type());
  encode_(..., code); //fill code with values
  codes.row(i) = code;
  std::cout<<"code= "<<code<<std::endl;
  std::cout<<"codes.row= "<<codes.row<<std::endl;
}
```

However the printed values are differents:

```
code= [-0.0018070865, -0.0088188984, -0.001866244, 0.0071420735, -0.00046708167, -0.0011722896, ...
codes.row= [0.091074832, 0.10463701, 0.060412209, 0.075102232, 0.036429934, 0.018214967, ...
```

Why this happens?

Comment: The right tool to solve such problems is your debugger. You should step through your code line-by-line *before* asking on Stack Overflow. For more help, please read [How to debug small programs (by Eric Lippert)](https://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/). At a minimum, you should \[edit] your question to include a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) example that reproduces your problem, along with the observations you made in the debugger.

Comment: I'm sorry, but you should ask before assuming that I don't know how to use your a debugger, which I know how to use. There are **plenty** of well rated questions as mine here. My code is minimal (no extra code is included, just the one that you need to understand the problem) complete (no information is missed to understand the problem) and veriefiable (the code works in a suitable program). Debugging OpenCV with conventional debuggers doesn't help since is a big frameworks and you cannot dig too much in the library.

Comment: Understand your framework before using it!

Comment: I'm sorry, are you saying that you now every single method of your framework? Well, good for you. In my opinion, it doesn't matter how simple a question is, instead it's important how **clear** the question is. This question is 100% clear and satisfy stackoverflow requirements. If you don't know OpenCV, please don't answer the question (or up/down vote it). I'm quite surprised that these basics notions are given from me to an user with such an experience as you are. Cheers.

Comment: I assume  this output `printing code outside: [ ..]` is produced by this line `std::cout<<"code= "<<code<<std::endl;` and what is `i` in `codes.row(i) = code;`

Comment: @rene Whooops, edited! :D

Comment: good ...  but it is still unclear what i means ...

Comment: @rene you're right (edited)

Comment: OK, I think I managed to achieve what the original commentor was after. Good luck with your question.

Comment: @rene Thanks, I'm sorry for my initial question

Comment: The last line printing `std::cout<<"codes.row= "<<codes.row<<std::endl;` should be `std::cout<<"codes.row= "<<codes.rows(i)<<std::endl;`, does it?

Answer (score 0):

Following the documentation of [Mat::row](http://docs.opencv.org/3.1.0/d3/d63/classcv_1_1Mat.html#acce30f9c4475038ee86ea8b24e00850a) I found out by myself that replacing:

```
  codes.row(i) = code;
```

with:

```
  code.row(0).copyTo(codes.row(i));
```

solved the problem...but why? :D I guess it's something related to reference headers, but I can't understand the mechanism in details.